# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-tether' in [..]/node_modules/pui-react-overlay-trigger

Tags: reactjs

It was working, randomly stopped working. `react-tether` is installed under *node_modules*.

**package.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.config.js --progress --inline --colors --no-info"
  },
  "private": true,
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "stage-0"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "5.6.23",
    "babel-core": "6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.11.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.14",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "0.25.0",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "file": "^0.2.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.4",
    "giphy-api": "1.2.1",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "inherits": "2.0.3",
    "less": "2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "2.2.3",
    "material-ui": "0.16.1",
    "minimatch": "3.0.3",
    "moment": "2.15.1",
    "pui-react-overlay-trigger": "6.0.2",
    "pui-react-tooltip": "6.0.2",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-addons-create-fragment": "15.3.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.3.2",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "15.3.2",
    "react-addons-transition-group": "15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "15.3.2",
    "react-highlight-words": "0.6.0",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "1.0.0",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^4.0.5",
    "react-timeout": "1.0.0",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "2.6.1",
    "redux-promise": "0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "2.1.0",
    "string-similarity": "^1.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "webpack": "1.13.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.7.2",
    "transfer-webpack-plugin": "0.1.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "1.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Downvoting without commenting sucks.

Comment: Almost certainly [for the urgent begging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495),  and in the title no less. 1.5K users should know better. (I normally downvote as a matter of course for this, but -4 will probably do!).

Comment: In general, things do not stop working randomly. Can you rebuild your project from a clean state, or perhaps wind it back a bit in your version control and build that from clean?

Comment: It looks like react-tether was updated, and now it seems to have an impact on pui-react-overlay-trigger - https://github.com/souporserious/react-tether package.json 0.5.4 release 4 hours ago, I assume the only way to fix this would be to have pui-react-overlay-trigger update to work with react-tether 0.5.4

Comment: 0.5.4 release was broken (https://github.com/souporserious/react-tether/issues/38) and pui-react-overlay-trigger was not installing exact versions so it picked the latest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By installing react-tether as a dependency of your app, it will override the version in pui-react-overlay-trigger

`npm install react-tether@0.5.2 --save-exact`

This made my version work.